# firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); crashing the application in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, crashlytics-android

i am creating a page for my chatting application and i encountred with a problem.
i am trying to connect my apk to firebase and using  `firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();`

1. gradle build succesfully
2. apk build succesfully
3. apk instal on device successfully

now the problem is when apk opens its switches to *otpActivity* and hence app close/crashes itself.

I check the error stats in logcat , hence it is showing error at `firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();`  code

**Note :** I am using the latest version of firebase and android studio and included each and every possible dependencies and library with minsdk 24

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

can you show your fragment/activity where the .getInstance is. Also the build gradle and the exact error.